# SetBinding for Listbox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

How to set DisplayMemberPathProperty and SelectedValuepathProperty for Listbox in codeBehind?

```
Listbox1.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = _ItemCollection});
```

The above line of code works fine and i can see the data in the listbox.

But when i try to set the displaymemberpathprop and selectedvaluememberpathprop its not working. I did something like this

```
Listbox1.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = _ItemCollection});
Listbox1.SetBinding(ListBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty, "FirstName") ;
Listbox1.SetBinding(ListBox.SelectedValuePathProperty, "Id");
```

please help

Thanks 
Sharath

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should not set bindings to the DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath properties unless you want this path to be dynamic (depend on the data). Instead you should just directly set this properties to the names of properties on the target object, like this:

```
Listbox1.DisplayMemberPath = "FirstName"; 
Listbox1.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
```